# Custom Ad Servers Facebook Instant Articles

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-instant-articles

there is any way to ad custom ad servers in facebook instant articles? According to the (poor) facebook instant documentation we need to wrap the javascript code inside a figure (with class op-ad) and an iframe.

There is any way to have a fallback ad server in case no ad is shown?

There is any way to collapse the position of the advertisement if no ad is showing? To prevent big blank spaces...

Suggestions and recommendations are very very welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

AdPlugg (including the free version) integrates with Facebook Instant Articles.

If you are using WordPress, you can use the [AdPlugg WordPress Ad Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/adplugg/) in combination with the [Instant Articles for WP plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fb-instant-articles/) (from Facebook/Automattic ) to automatically place ads within your Facebook Instant Articles feed.

If you aren't using WordPress, you can use AdPlugg iframe urls in your op-ad tags.

Once you are using AdPlugg for the iframes, you can control what will appear there using the controls at adplugg.com. You can rotate and track your ads, use ads from different sources, etc.

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any way to collapse the iframe if no ad is showing. However with AdPlugg, you can create a house ad or similar to fallback to if you haven't sold the spot.

There are instructions for how to set everything up here: https://www.adplugg.com/blog/facebook-instant-article-ads

*Disclaimer: I work for AdPlugg.*